# Changing Dynamic URL through .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to change URL from http://example.com/?a=cust&page=abc to http://example.com/abc .

I tried the code mentioned below, but it got  me stuck:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?a=cust&page([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?a=cust&page$1 [L,QSA]
```

So any help on how to get it work correctly? :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You regex in first `RewriteCond` isn't correct. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?a=cust&page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?a=cust&page$1 [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT:**

This is the new rule you want:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?a=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked!! :D However now /?a=abc doesn't works, how to get both of 'em to work together?

Comment: In what ways `/?a=abc` isn't working? Was it working before? Is `/?a=abc` giving 404 to you?

Comment: The script I've has several links as example.com/?a=abc & several as example.com/?a=cust&page=abc , now with the above rule only /?a=cust&paage=abc are being redirected as example.com/abc but not example.com/?a=abc - how to get both the pages work as example.com/abc .

Comment: They both can be redirected to `/abc` in browser but problem is internal routing `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?a=cust&page$1 [L,QSA]` then always route it to `/?a=cust&page=abc` and you will not get `/?a=abc` as a result of that.

Comment: hmmm, a bit confusing, can you please edit it in the solution part, if possible. I've been doing it in several ways from more than 4 hours and all wrongly done. :(

Comment: Thanks, but now 500 ISE. Looks like for me either of the one will only work. :D Thanks anyway. :)